# inverted index in python with spacy as tokenization and persistent relation to original documents

Tags: python, nlp, inverted-index, spacy

I want to build an inverted index in python using the great https://spacy.io/ library to tokenize the words.

They provide a great example how to concurrently perform the preprocessing and end up with a nice list of documents ready to be indexed.

```
texts = [u'One document.', u'...', u'Lots of documents']
# .pipe streams input, and produces streaming output
iter_texts = (texts[i % 3] for i in range(100000000))
for i, doc in enumerate(nlp.pipe(iter_texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)):
    assert doc.is_parsed
    if i == 30:
        break
    print(i)
    print(doc)
```

What I do not understand so far is how to maintain a relationship (file path/ URL) to the original documents using this method, i.e. to store it as an additional attribute with each document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/172

```
def gen_items():
    print("Yield 0")
    yield (0, 'Text 0')
    print("Yield 1")
    yield (1, 'Text 1')
    print("Yield 2")
    yield (2, 'Text 2')

gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(gen_items())
ids = (id_ for (id_, text) in gen1)
texts = (text for (id_, text) in gen2)
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)
for id_, doc in zip(ids, docs):
    print(id_, doc.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find the `doc.user_data` dictionary useful. Note that it's not currently serialized in the `doc.to_bytes()` output, so you'll need to store it separately. Serialising as a tuple `(pickle(doc.user_dict), doc.to_bytes())` might work.

Comment: But how to fill it with values i.e. the file paths during execution of `nlp.pipe(iter_texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)`?

Comment: Is there any possibility to "adapt" the pipe method to actually take some ID values?